# sql command to linq

Tags: asp.net, linq

i can not convert the sql command code to linq.
please convert sql Command to linq

```
select * from Student Where Id Not In (select Nm from Student)
```

thanks

Comment: as opposed to where Id != Nm? from s in Student where Id != Nm select s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
YourDataContext dc = new YourDataContext();

var query =
    from st in dc.Students
    where !(from n in dc.Students
            select n.Nm)
           .Contains(st.Id)
    select st;
```

Comment: @maktab: hop you know how to say thanks in StackOverflow. (accept if this works for you)

Comment: @maktab if this is the answer for your question, mark it as answer by click on the right mark. It will helpful to others as well :)